# ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> requestCode cannot be higher than 16 bits

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, registerforactivityresult

I'm updating the way that my app get images from gallery. I know that in the old way, which was `startActivityForResult()`, we can send a custom requestCode. However, in the `ActivityResultLauncher` we can't, right? It is automatically generated, so, with that being said, I'll show you my problem:

```
class TesteActivity: AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var resultLauncherPhotoPicker: ActivityResultLauncher<Intent>

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.teste)

        val imageView = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.myImageView)

        resultLauncherPhotoPicker = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
            if (result.resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                val data = result.data
                val imageUri = data?.data
                imageView.setImageURI(imageUri)
            }
        }

        myButton.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
            intent.type = "image/*"
            resultLauncherPhotoPicker.launch(intent)
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code snippet that don't run on my app, I get a error saying that the requestCode can't be higher than 16bits. When I debug the method that checks the requestCode, it does go over than 16 bits. But the main problem is: Why? If I can't send a custom requestCode, why is the requestCode automatically generated by the launcher wrong? I tried this exact snippet on a new empty project on my Android Studio and it WORKED. The same thing. What am I missing?

Comment: Sounds like you are using an ancient version of Fragments (either directly or because you are using an old version of AppCompat). What are your dependencies?